# multiple submit buttons on the same page in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

multiple submit buttons on the same page in oracle apex?

we have two (2) regions and each region has its own submit button (calling process). 
The issue is region 1 has submit button and also validating region 2 items which i don't want , i just want to only validate region 1 items on region 1 submit.

please help me out. I am using oracle application express 18.2

[image]

Comment: What *code*, @Yogesh? Did you ever do anything in Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at validation's properties (on the "Processing" tab), check its "Server-side Condition" section. It allows you to specify **WHEN BUTTON PRESSED** property so - set it to a button which belongs to that region.

Comment: Alternatively, buttons and declarative actions allow you to nominate the REQUEST value, which you can test in the validation/process/branch conditions, if processes run under multiple buttons.

Comment: i have not set any server-side condition with  button

under server-side condition (for Process)
when button pressed property give button name
Type : Item is Not Null
Item : Item Name


but again validate on both region items 
is it because that i have set button action is "submit Page" under behavior ?
i am not sure

Comment: We aren't discussing *process*, but *validation*. I re-read what I've previously written, and I still think that it is correct.

Comment: @Littlefoot  can you please answer this query  ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647814/human-readable-urls-in-oracle-apex

Answer (score 0):

Select when button pressed condition.