# human readable URLs in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

how to make human readable URLs in oracle apex
currently my url seems like

```
https://example.com/apex/f?p=107:1:13482402024834:::::
```

what i want my database application url looks like.

```
https://example.com/apex/home
```

i am using oracle apex 18.2

Comment: You asked for my assistance. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know that. On the other hand, you don't expect users to actually *type* the URL, do you? Provide this: `https://example.com/apex/f?p=107`, which is quite enough to log-in to the application because the rest is irrelevant (page number and session ID); application ID is all they need. Besides, they should bookmark (i.e. put your application into the favorites) and access the application with a *click*, not by *typing* anything into the address bar.

Comment: Please refer [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662744/need-help-regarding-masking-of-url-for-oracle-application-pages

Comment: You can also use alias for app and pages. Instead of a link with f?p=138:85 you can use a url like this f?p=google:home

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do that. Oracle Apex release 20.1 comes by default with readable URL structure while allows you to change back to older type URL

Comment: It really look much better. It is a pain to write because it's alot of text, but it is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can define DAD in the database, and provide name for the apex application in user-interface of application properties the url will have the name of application instead app number, aslo to mask the page numbers you can give alias to pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option till Apex 19.2.
In Apex 20.1 release there is an option to Modify the URL
Please refer the below link for detailed clarification

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/understanding-friendly-url-syntax.html#GUID-716B85EC-2D9B-49F7-BABE-2C4CA347F198

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex 18.2 have no option like that.